# How to get column names of table using coredata

Tags: iphone, core-data

In my iPhone application I have used coredata.

I want columnnames (fieldname) of table using coredata.

I have search for that but not finding way to get it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSManagedObjectModel` has a method called `entities` that gives a bunch of `NSEntityDescription` (tables) and in that class you find `attributesByName` and `relationshipsByName` which gives you the columns.

The model you can get by calling `[[<yourManagedObjectContext> persistentStoreCoordinator] managedObjectModel]`.